# Downloading file in php has the path of the file also which I dont want

Tags: php

I am trying to download files using the following code which is in "download.php":

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
//header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

I am calling this download.php from a link. eg.,

> download.php?file=user_songs/57/mp3/Satru_Munbu.mp3

But the donloaded file name is changed. It appears like "user_songs-57-mp3-Satru_Munbu.mp3"

It seems like the full path that I am passing gets appended. Can anyone help me how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$file` contains the full contents of the `file=` URL parameter, which is the full pathname. You can use `basename()` to extract just the filename part.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

Comment: yes. I just realized that filename does the magic.  I did by modifying like<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$filename = basename($file);

header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
//header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>

Answer (score 0):

"/" is a reserved character so you need to URL encode your path:

```
download.php?file=user_songs%2F57%2Fmp3%2FSatru_Munbu.mp3
```

By the way, be careful because anyone can access any file in your system with your code (as long as the Apache process can access it). For example, `download.php?file=%2Fetc%2Fpasswd` would download your /etc/passwd file.

Comment: I thought this was the solution too, but it seems you can pass '/' without encoding it and it still reads fine in the PHP script